# Python Checking If Multiple Programs are running and then upping a value written to a file

Tags: python

First of all I'm quite new to programming so sorry for the badly formatted/dodgy code

I am trying to make a program that tracks the amount of time certain programs is running. It sees if a program is running and then adds 1 to a variable which is then written to a file. The problem is I cannot run multiple loops at once to check if those programs are running. This leads to my code only checking if the first one is running.

My question is, is it possible to make several infinite loops at once to see if a program is running all at once. If so how do I do this. If there is another alternate solution that can accomplish the same thing please let me know down below.

I didnt know how to check if a program is running so i took the code used from [here](https://thispointer.com/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-by-name-and-find-its-process-id-pid/)

The code I have right now is:

```
import time
import psutil


def programrunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    # Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;


def write(file, var):
    store_thing = open(file, "w+")
    store_thing.write(var)
    store_thing.close()


def create(filename):
    open(filename, "x")


def read(filename):
    read_p = open(filename, "r")
    read_p.mode == "r"
    content = read_p.read()
    return content


def whilerun(program):
    while programrunning(program) == True:
        var = read(program + ".txt")
        programvar = var
        programvar = int(programvar) + int(1)
        time.sleep(1)
        write(program + ".txt", str(programvar))
    while programrunning(program) == False:
        var = read(program + ".txt")
        programvar = var
        programvar = int(programvar) + int(1)
        time.sleep(1)
        write(program + ".txt", str(programvar))


whilerun("program1")
whilerun("program2")
whilerun("program3")
```

Comment: I don't think you need multiple running scripts. You can get the set of running processes once by doing `running = {proc.name().lower() for proc in psutil.process_iter()}`, and then for each process name you care about (stored in a list), check if `name in running`, and do whatever storage you want with that info.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a loop for your programs.

```
programs = ["program1", "program2", "program3"]

def whilerun(programs):
    while True:
        any_alive = False    # flag for inf loop prevention
        for program in programs:
            if programrunning(program):
                # -- do sth for program running --
                any_alive = True
            else:
                # -- do sth for program NOT running
                pass

        if not any_alive:    # stop the loop if all processes are dead
            break
```